# After logging out from another tab, I still have user in my scope['session'] in django channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I want to disconnect the WebSocket connection while the user has logged out from another tab. So, I use `get_user()` in Django channels to check if a user is still logged in(in session).

I opened multiple tabs at the same time. And I logged out from one of the tabs. However, after logging out, it still shows the `user.is_authenticated = True` and I can have a user from `self.scope["user"]`.
What's a problem with my code here?

Here is my code.
In views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

...
class Logout(LogoutView):
    template_name = "account/logout.html" # log user out
```

In cousumers.py

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer

class Chat(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
...
    def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        message = content['message']

        user = async_to_sync(get_user)(self.scope)

        logging.info(user.is_authenticated) # still true after logging out
        logging.info(f'user is {self.scope["user"]}') # show the user as well
        if user is None:
            return self.disconnect()
        self.send_json(content={'message': f'receive: {message}'})
...
```

I've checked the documentation ans source files of both `Django` and `Django-channels`, and tried to use `logout` from `channels.auth` at `consumers.py`. It works but not what I want to use. I expect that I can get the correct session without user status.